# Add icon to Toolbar in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, toolbar

I'm trying to add an icon, which is located into my drawable directory, to the right of my toolbar, right before the classic "vertical three dots". This is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        style="@style/HeaderBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/miCompose"
            android:icon="@drawable/eraser"
            android:title="Compose"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="26dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/my_toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that I get this error on the line

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class item

This is the style I would like to recreate in my app:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use icon in menu method

set Support Action Bar

```
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        val inflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_logout, menu)
        return true
    }
```